# Magento 2: Override for product custom option value Interface and model file

Tags: custom-options, products, rest-api, magento2.3.1

I have added custom product option value to below interface `ProductCustomOptionValuesInterface.php` and `Value.php` model file.

> File path: magento2/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Api/Data/ProductCustomOptionValuesInterface.php
>
> File path:
>   magento2/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product/Option/Value.php

But how to override above vendor file code to custom module.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: which method do you want to override in value.php? I think you can use plugin or preferences to override value.php.

Comment: I need to add my custom new methods in `ProductCustomOptionValuesInterface.php` and `Value.php`

Comment: In this case, I would suggest to override only value.php file using preferences and add your custom function because Magento does not allow you to override interface.

Comment: After override only value.php how can add custom get set method in interface ?

Comment: @Nits Can you give me example for same. Interface and Model file ?

Comment: @KirtiNariya hi, did you get answer for this, what to do if the core interface class doesn't have an extension attribute functions, I am also facing same issue for this interface, Need to add 2 new functions of set & get Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\CategoryTreeInterface

Comment: @KirtiNariya have you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2 does not allow us to override the interfaces.

You can use Extension attributes for these things you can get help from online docs how to create Extension attributes in Magento 2 for interfaces.

Comment: Can you give me example to create extension attribute for rest API product options and how that extension attribute get set from plugin or model ?

Comment: @AmrtiPalSingh I was tried to add Extension attributes but Can't able to add Extension attributes.

https://github.com/magento/community-features/issues/30

Comment: take a look here https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/extension_attributes/adding-attributes.html

Comment: Yes. But can't able to add Extension attributes to product custom option.
Please check github issue.
https://github.com/magento/community-features/issues/30

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by creating the Extension attributes.

Refer to this link: https://www.zynovo.com/blog/magento-2-extension-attributes/

Comment: Thanks for help I appreciate it. But Extension attributes not working for  `Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductCustomOptionValuesInterface`

Please check github issue.
https://github.com/magento/community-features/issues/30