# Magento 2.3.2 backorder is not working when check in 2.3.1 its working perfectly but not in 2.3.2

Tags: magento2, backorder

I am using magento 2.3.2 and I am trying set backorder allow below quantity 0 and manage stock yes, but in frontend outof stock product add to cat button not showing.

Answer (score 1):

For Backorders, you need to set below things in product

> Stock Status : In Stock
>
> Quantity : 0
>
> Advanced Inventory > Backorders : Allow QTY Below 0.

`Save Product`

That's it. After making above change in any product that product you can add in cart from frontend.

If you'll set `Stock Status` : `Out of stock` then Magento will not display "Add to cart" button and "QTY" input box. Because here in this file there is one condition `$_product->isSaleable()` this will return `false` if we select `Out of stock` in product. So just set `In Stock` in `Stock Status` and check that will work.

You can refer these both files

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/form.phtml

Check this condition in above file

```
<?php if (!$block->hasOptions()) :?>
    <?= $block->getChildHtml('product_info_form_content') ?>
<?php else :?>
    <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $block->getOptionsContainer() == 'container1') :?>
        <?= $block->getChildChildHtml('options_container') ?>
    <?php endif;?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml

Hope this will works for you!

Comment: Please help on this question.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/293336/magento-2-override-for-product-custom-option-value-interface-and-model-file

Comment: If above solution helps you then please do upvote and accept my answer. Thanks :)