# Magento2 Installation Problem on Windows 10

Tags: magento2, xampp, windows10

I tried to install `Magento 2` on `Windows10`, `XAMPP`. It experiment got a successfully installed page. But it is not work correctly. This is a browser image
[image]

Anyone knows how to solve it ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: please check your php, mysql version

Comment: Its Not Preferred to install magento on Ubuntu see https://meetanshi.com/blog/magento-2-system-requirements/

Comment: Magento 2 System Requirements
Operating Systems Requirements
Linux distributors such as CentOS, Ubuntu, Debian or RedHat Enterprise Linux are easy to install Magento 2.

Answer (score 2):

I have same issue to with magento 2.3 on Windows 10, backoffice page show blank page with brown background.

after searching the problem on the web, finally found solution

1. open file `/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template/File/Validator.php`
   in magento install dir , you will find on `LINE NO. 138`

> $realPath = $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path);

replace with :

```
$realPath = str_replace('\\', '/', $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path));
```

Your login page showing, but the icon is missing in login page and after login

2. open file app/etc/di.xml in magento install dir, find

> Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink

and replace with

```
Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy
```

1. Then go to var/cache , delete all folder / file
2. refresh the page, done.

If still face issue then go to cmd open your magento dir then run all cmd one by one

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but I can't find "$realPath = $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path);" in /vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template/File/Validator.php file

Comment: which version you are using..?

Comment: in magento 2.3 you will find on LINE NO. 138

Comment: @SangeetaChandaliya
Please help on this question.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/293336/magento-2-override-for-product-custom-option-value-interface-and-model-file

Answer (score 0):

version :2.3.3 
But I see a thing ;program looks for http://localhost/magento2/pub/static/version1571915454/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/fonts/opensans/ folder for some files but Really this version1571915454 folder is not exist

Comment: In Magento 2.3.3 you will find "YourMagentofolder /vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template/File/Validator.php" this file..if not found this file that means you don't download proper file. It's Magento default file.

Comment: Pub/static is generated folder, you don't need to change in this file.

Comment: Validator.php  file is exist and Pub/static/frontend folder is exist but pub/static/version1571915454/frontend... folder is not exist. each installation comes with another number( /version##########)

Comment: you don't need to update in pub folder file, you should need to update in "vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template/File/Validator.php" this file. please read my answer properly.

Comment: the line 138 of validator.php =   foreach ($directories as $directory) {
            if (0 === strpos($this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path), $directory)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

Comment: before foreach loop one line is there "$realPath = $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path);" you should need to replace with $realPath = str_replace('\\', '/', $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path));

Comment: protected function isPathInDirectories($path, $directories)
    {
        if (!is_array($directories)) {
            $directories = (array)$directories;
        }
        //$realPath = $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path);
  $realPath = str_replace('\\', '/', $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path));
        foreach ($directories as $directory) {
            if (0 === strpos($realPath, $directory)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

Comment: ohhh .. thank you very very much it is ok ....

Comment: welcome..if your issue solved then please accept my answer by clicking on tick mark...so other person also get help.