# Default zip code for shipping address

Tags: magento2.3, shipping-address, zipcode

How can I set default zip code for the shipping address??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create file in module `app\code\Ketan\Module\etc\di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
        <plugin name="ketan_checkout_layout_processor" type="Ketan\Module\Plugin\Block\LayoutProcessor" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Create Plugin file `app\code\Ketan\Module\Plugin\Block\LayoutProcessor.php`

```
<?php
namespace Ketan\Module\Plugin\Block;

class LayoutProcessor
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject
     * @param array $jsLayout
     * @return array
     */
    public function afterProcess(
        \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
        array $jsLayout
    ) {
        $postcode = 369856;

        /*================Start For Shipping Address ===========*/

        if(isset($jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
            ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset'])) {

            $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']
            ['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['postcode']['value'] = $postcode;

        }

        /*================End For Shipping Address ===========*/




        /*================Start For Billing Address ===========*/
        if(isset($jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
            ['payment']['children']['payments-list'])) {
            $paymentsList = $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
            ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children'];

            foreach ($paymentsList as $paymentCode => $payment) {
                if(strpos($paymentCode, '-form') === false) {
                    continue;
                }
                $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
                ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children'][$paymentCode]['children']['form-fields']['children']['postcode']['value'] = $postcode;
            }
        }
         if(isset($jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children'])){


            $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
            ['payment']['children']['afterMethods']['children']['billing-address-form']['children']['form-fields']['children']['postcode']['value'] = $postcode;

        }

        /*================End For Billing Address ===========*/
        return $jsLayout;
    }

}
```

Default postcode for shipping / billing address 365689

Comment: Please help on this question.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/293336/magento-2-override-for-product-custom-option-value-interface-and-model-file